# Serial loop number add PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-scripts

I need insert into my PostgreSQL database , please help me for wrote script for this script

```
INSERT INTO accounts (serial, active, name)
VALUES (111100000000, true, 111100000000);
```

****Start Number 111100000000****
End Number 111199999999

anyone can help me for this script  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [generate_series](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) function

```
INSERT INTO accounts (serial, active, name)
select generated_value,true, generated_value 
from generate_series(111100000000 , 111199999999,1) as generated_value
```

With this, you are going to insert ~100M row!